# Duplicate where the new question has better answers than the old

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

[This newly-asked question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71730/is-the-password-z-more-secure-than-the-password-a) is clearly a duplicate of [this older one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64202/does-it-take-longer-to-brute-force-a-password-starting-with-z-than-one-starting), but I think it's got better answers.  What's the correct way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 5):

The best route is exactly what you have done - post in here, or flag to moderators. We'll get a good look and take one of 3 actions:

- leave as is (default, especially if the old answers are ok) - possibly add a link to point from the old one to the new
- change the dupe direction (if the answers on the new question are much better)
- merge (if there are good answers on both sides)

In this case it appears a merge is likely to be the best bet as there are a few good answers on each.